# snakemake different environments per subworkflow

Tags: snakemake

I have made two separate analysis pipelines in snakemake with each there own conda environments. Now I'm making an umbrella snakemake with the two pipelines as subworkflows. Is it possible to use the two other pipelines in there own environment? I cant find it back in the documentation. And I prefer not to use separate environments for each rule of the subworkflow using the --use-conda option.

I hope somebody can help me out how to solve it, or do I need to create one large environment containing all the tools of both pipelines, this doesn't seem very efficient to me.

```
SAMPLES=['a','b','c']

subworkflow one:
    workdir:"snake_one/"
    configfile:"snake_one/config.yaml"

subworkflow two:
    workdir:"snake_two/"
    configfile:"snake_two/config.yaml"


rule All:
  input:
    one(expand("../reports/{sample}-report.html",sample=SAMPLES)),
    two(final.txt),
```

ps. I did also asked this question on the snakemake forum, but I saw that this was the better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should refer to this page: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html?highlight=envs

You can have one env for the whole pipeline or one for each rule using the conda: entry and --use-conda option.